# BroadcastReceiver still work after unregister on Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver, xamarin.forms

I am developing Xamarin Forms app, but I want to use `BroadcastReciever`, when I change network state. Here is my code:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    IsVisible = true;
    base.OnStart();
}

protected override void OnPause()
{
    _receiver = new InternetBroadcastReceiver();
    LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this).UnregisterReceiver(_receiver);//doesn't work
    IsVisible = false;
    Debug.WriteLine("pause");
    base.OnPause();
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    IsVisible = true;
    Debug.WriteLine("resume");
    SendReceiver();
    base.OnResume();
}

private void SendReceiver()
{
    LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this).RegisterReceiver(_receiver, new IntentFilter(Android.Net.ConnectivityManager.ConnectivityAction));
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(InternetBroadcastReceiver));
    SendBroadcast(intent);//work only with global
}
```

Yeah, that strange, that `SendBroadcast` method works only when I call it from how global receiver. I don't know, what an issue is this. Maybe it is a problem of Xamarin Forms, or maybe I do something wrong? Receiver I register only on code, without manifest.

Comment: If your `InternetBroadcastReceiver` is receiving that broadcast, then it must be registered in the manifest somehow, because you're using an explicit `Intent`. I don't do Xamarin, but I believe there's some sort of annotation you can put on the class declaration that causes it to be entered in the manifest at build time. Also, Receivers registered with `LocalBroadcastManager` can only get broadcasts sent with `LocalBroadcastManager`, so your `SendBroadcast()` call is not broadcasting to that Receiver instance you register in your code there.

Comment: @MikeM. and how i should disable it, when i register him from manifest?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you want to disable a manifest-registered Receiver from code, you can do it with `PackageManager`'s `SetComponentEnabledSetting()` method. If you mean you don't want it registered in the manifest at all, [this page](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.BroadcastReceiverAttribute/) shows what I was talking about; the `[BroadcastReceiver...]` line, right above the `class` declaration. You'd remove that, I believe.

Comment: Also, I just noticed, in your code, you're instantiating a new Receiver right before unregistering it with `LocalBroadcastManager`. You don't want to do that, as it will not be the same Receiver instance that you registered.

Comment: @MikeM. I will try, thanks